# Delete from SQLite and Update Listview with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

How can i delete an item from a listView which is backed by SQLite and update the listView with the new contents?

I've tried to follow solutions to other examples, but can't seem to remove the items.

Class which shows data in listView:

```
public class MyFeedsScreen extends ListActivity {

DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Set the layout of MyFeeds screen
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_feeds_screen);


    dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(MyFeedsScreen.this);
    displayList();
}

public void displayList() {

    //Call method to open database
    dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();

    //Open database and get instance of database handler
    dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    final Cursor cursor = dbHandler.getData();
    //Takes string array for title, link and description and maps them different textView items
    String from[] = new String[]{dbHandler.columnTitle, dbHandler.link, dbHandler.description};
    int to[] = new int[]{R.id.textView1};
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, cursor, from, to, 0);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    lv.setLongClickable(true);
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            try {
                dbHandler.open();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            final String itemId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

            dbHandler.deleteItemFromTable(itemId);
            dbHandler.getData();

            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            displayList();

            Toast.makeText(MyFeedsScreen.this, "Item has been deleted from MyFeeds!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            return true;
        }
    });
}//displayList()}//class
```

DatabaseHandler.java - methods to populate listview and delete items

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "news_db";
public static SQLiteDatabase db;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 43;
protected static final String TABLE_NEWS = "news";
private static final String TAG = "TAG";
private static final String TAG1 = "TAG1";
static String columnTitle = "title";
protected static final String _id = "_id";
protected static final String link = "link";
protected static final String description = "description";


//Methods for tables
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_TABLE_NEWS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NEWS + "(_id VARCHAR, title TEXT, link TEXT, description TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NEWS);
    Log.w(TAG, "Database has been created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NEWS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}


//Method to insert new rssItem object to the database
public void insertRssItem(RssItem rssItem) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("_id", rssItem._id);
    contentValues.put("title", rssItem.title);
    contentValues.put("link", rssItem.link);
    contentValues.put("description", rssItem.description);
    db.insert(TABLE_NEWS, "title", contentValues);
    Log.d(TAG1, "ITEM SAVED IN DATABASE!!!");
}//insert item method


//get data from database for listview
public Cursor getData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, title, link, description FROM " + TABLE_NEWS, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(cursor.getColumnName(1)));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return cursor;
}

//Method to delete item from database, on long-pressing listView
public void deleteItemFromTable(String rowId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.delete(TABLE_NEWS, _id + " = " + rowId, null);

    Log.w("Item has been deleted", "*****************");
    db.close();

}}
```

When i select the item the toast shows on the screen and the logcat shows the "Item has been deleted" log tag.

Comment: Do you get any SQL exeception or error message? Show us the stack. Also, if you have any constraint created (e.g. primary key, composite key using some columns), a delete will not work until you drop all your constraints. Confirm that this is not the case and update your question with the error message (if any)

Comment: Thanks for your response, i've updated my question to show the full databaseHandler class. The logCat doesn't show an error though, just the tag included within the method.